# How can I join an English chat channel?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

When I login to the game, I'm always placed in a channel "General Chat (deDE)". Unfortunately I don't understand German, so when I join a match I'm placed with German players who no doubt don't understand my English either.

So how can I join an English channel?

I have tried `/join General Chat (` but I just get about 15 deDE channels listed as possibilities.

Comment: I did it somehow 3 month ago. Mb try to write it by your own: /join General Chat (enEN)

Comment: you can type /list to see all channels and then you just have to click the one you wanna join

Comment: @klm123 The problem with writing your own channel is if you get it wrong, you'll create an empty channel and join that as well as your existing channels.

Comment: Ok. I typed /join General Chat (en and saw 3 /join General Chat (enGB). Similarly /join General Chat (es gives /join General Chat (esES) (which I never wanted to join). So @/join General Chat (enGB)@ should be work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe "**/join General Chat (enGB)**" is what you are looking for.

I typed "/join General Chat (en" and the game hinted me this channel: "/join General Chat (enGB)".
To be sure, that this is not the one I accidentally created earlier I tried the same procedure with "Espaniol" channel (that I don't speak and would never try to join/create). The game hinted similarly: "/join General Chat (esES)". So "/join General Chat (enGB)" should work.